# Core location problem

Tags: core-location

I'm trying to find the current location and then use the geocoder to find the city,state. 
This is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{  
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
    //NSLog(@"Reverse Geocoder completed");
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;

    NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    NSString *state = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
    location = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@", city, state];
}
```

I've tested the reverse Geocoder and it works fine when I manually type create a coordinate of my current location: (50.4, -104.6). However, when I run this code with a breakpoint in "didUpdateToLocation" delegate method, the newLocation gives me a coordinate of 37.3,-122.0 which is Cupertino, California. I think I'm setting up the locationManager wrong so any ideas?

Comment: Are you running in the simulator?  I think that would explain Cupertino being the only location - no GPS unit in your Mac!

Comment: Yeah, i def ran the simulator instead. Let me try on my device and see what I get. Thanks a lot